# osgeo4mac QGIS 3.4.4 issues with gdal's merge

Tags: qgis, osgeo, gdal-merge

I'm trying to run the gdal mosaic tool from QGIS3 homebrew osgeo4mac, but when I run it I get this error:

```
2019-02-11T18:25:17     INFO    gdal_merge.py -ot Float32 -of GTiff -o /private/var/folders/fc/8d63rgj567954sphjm_18jxc0000gn/T/processing_b134aaed11d54580be7a0a55892749b4/852f65f2e4174785a1b7b8edc21053e9/OUTPUT.tif --optfile /private/var/folders/fc/8d63rgj567954sphjm_18jxc0000gn/T/processing_b134aaed11d54580be7a0a55892749b4/mergeInputFiles.txt
2019-02-11T18:25:17     INFO    GDAL execution console output
             Traceback (most recent call last):

              File "/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/bin/gdal_merge.py", line 38, in 

              from osgeo import gdal

              File "/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in 

              _gdal = swig_import_helper()

              File "/usr/local/opt/gdal2-python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 13, in swig_import_helper

              import _gdal

             ImportError: No module named _gdal
```

It seems strange because I can run other gdal tools but not that one.

Comment: A similar old issue related to yours has a solution at this link http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Mac-OSX-ImportError-No-module-named-gdal-td4472441.html

Comment: thanks but that question is related to QGIS 2 (it was asked in 2012) and makes reference to a no-longer-existing plugin called GdalTools